# Line-insensitive pattern-matching – How can some context be displayed?

Tags: regex, bash, sed, pattern-matching

I'm looking for a technique to search a file for a pattern (typically a phrase) that may span multiple lines, and print the match with some surrounding context *on one line*. The file's lines may be too long or too short for a sensible amount of context; I'm not concerned to print a single line of the *file*, as you might do with `grep`, but rather to print *onto* a single line of my *terminal*.

### Basic requirements

- Show a specified number of characters before and after the match, even if it straddles lines.
- Show newlines as ‘`\n`’ to prevent flooding the terminal with whitespace if there are many short lines.
- Prefix output line with line and column number of the start of the match.
- Preferably a `sed` oneliner.

So far, I'm assuming that the pattern has a constant length shorter than the width of the terminal, which is okay and very useful for most phrases I might want to search for.

### Further considerations

I would be interested to see how the following could also be achieved using `sed` or the likes:

- Prefix output line with line and column number *range* of the match.
- Generalise for variable length patterns, truncating the middle of the match to ‘`[…]`’ if too long.
- Can I avoid using something like ‘`[ \n]`’ between words in a phrase regex on a file that has been ‘hard-wrapped’ using newlines, without altering what's printed?
- Using the output of `stty size` to dynamically determine the terminal width may be useful, though I'd probably prefer to leave it static in case I want to resize the terminal or use it from `screen` attached from terminals of different sizes.

### Examples

The basic idea for 10 characters of context would be something like:

‘excessively long line with **match** in the middle\n’ → ‘line with **match** in the mi’
‘short\nlines\n\n**match**\nlots\nof\nshort\nlines\n’ → ‘rt\nlines\n\n**match**\nlots\nof\ns’

Comment: Can you post example text and what you like to get out of it?

Comment: @Jotne: In my first example, the screen would be flooded if `grep` were to be used; in my second `grep` would display no context at all. This is what I want to avoid. I think ideally, the escaped newline characters as well as Unicode characters should be counted as the number of virtual characters that they show up as in the displayed output, rather than just counting bytes, but this is a minor detail which would be less obvious in a longer example.

Comment: You may use `awk` and then set record selector to give block, then you can use commands to search within block like you would do in line search.  This would then avoid problems with newline etc.  But to help with this, we need to see how the data is built.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a command to return the 20 characters surrounding a pattern, spanning newlines and including them as a character:

```bash
$ input="test.txt"
$ pattern="match"
$ tr '\n' '~' < "$input" | grep -o ".\{10\}${pattern}.\{10\}" | sed 's/~/\\n/g'

line with match in the mi
rt\nlines\n\nmatch\nlots\nof\ns
```

With row number of the match as well:

```
$ paste <(grep -n ${pattern} "$input" | cut -d: -f1) \
<(tr '\n' '~' < "$input" | grep -o ".\{10\}${pattern}.\{10\}" | sed 's/~/\\n/g')

1       line with match in the mi
5       rt\nlines\n\nmatch\nlots\nof\ns
```

I realise this doesn't quite fulfill all of your basic requirements, but am not good enough with awk to do better (guess this is technically possible in sed, but I don't want to think about what it would look like).